# How to avoid data reload on android device back button

Tags: android, button, android-activity, reload, back

I am using android tab based application with TabGroupActivity, the application have a ListActivity "A" which drills down to a detail activity "D", on detail activity when i click device back button it navigate back to ListActivtiy "A" and relaods the data (ProgressBar shows progress on back button).
How can i avoid reloading of data on back buttuon ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: in onCreate event i am calling a webservice for data loading which is called againg on clicking back button, i want to avoid calling webservice on back button.

Comment: if that's the same data  - see my answer below, otherwise - I do not think you have to many options but to reload it

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) to save what's needed to be saved and then restore your activity in [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29)

Comment: I use following code to save a variable value IsAlreadyLoaded.  `@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
 savedInstanceState.putBoolean("IsAlreadyLoaded", true);
 super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);    

}`  and retreive this value in oncreate event when back to activity. however i got savedInstanceState as null and i m not able to get what i have saved.
In below code savedInstanceState is always null
`boolean myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("IsAlreadyLoaded");

Comment: where do you implement onSaveInstanceState? can you post all code where you save/retrieve the data?

Comment: onCreate is not called when you come back to a previous activity, except if the memory was low, and system decided to call onDestroy on the activity.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't really understand. When you press back, the current activity is destroy, and the previous activity call onStart/onResume. Here, it seems this is the TabHostActivity. If the only way to load data in your list activity is in the onCreate, so it seems like the TabHostActivity recreate all tab when onStart or onResume is called. But i have read that you need to call specially tabhost.destroyActivity and startActivity to "recreate" activities. My point is that it shouldn't call the onCreate of your ListActivity when you press back, you should look why.

Comment: @Asahi, i override the onSaveInstanceState and save a variable with value true, like below
`@Override public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) { savedInstanceState.putBoolean("IsAlreadyLoaded", true); super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState); }`  
and then try to get that value in onCreate like follwoing  
`boolean myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("IsAlreadyLoaded"); `  
but fails to get variable value because savedInstanceState object is null

Comment: what class you implement it in?

Comment: its an activity which is launched on first tab of the application.

Comment: The first time you will launch the activity, savedInstanceState will be null, because there is not yet saved data. Do you check that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Activity LifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) :

When you go to another activity, and press back, it will call finish(). The first activity was on the onStop() method because it was no longer visible. So, when you come back to the first activity, it will call the method onStart(), and on Stop().

Try to overload this method without calling the super method (it might be a very bad idea).

You can also try to remember the position when you was (get the index of the current tab), and on the onResume() method, set the current tab to this index.

You just need an int attribute savedPosition in your listactivity.
    private int savedPosition = -1;

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
  savedPosition = getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition();

  super.onPause();
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  if(savedPosition != -1) {
    getList().setSelection(savedPosition);
  }
}
```